# How to fit the TextView text in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, textview, horizontalscrollview

Well, i took a `TextView` inside `HorizontalScrollView` to scroll the text if it gets too large. But unfortunately, the text isn't aligning properly- form left a lot of text gets hidden if the text is large.

**Layout:**

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/retBal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Amount is being processed.."
            android:textColor="@color/_2ndGray"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**In activity class:**

```
TextView txtVwRetBal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.retBal);

txtVwRetBal.setText("Balance is xyz11111111122222222222222333333333444444444555555555666666666677777777788888pqr");
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you need to use horizontal scroll outside? Just add a horizontal scrollbar in your textview- as @Vishwajit Palankar said. Additionally add the  android:ellipsize="none" and  android:singleLine="true" in your xml layout file.

eg:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

and in java file initiate the TextView and add the scrollingMovementMethod()

```
 TextView txtv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
 txtv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
 txtv.setText("balance is : " + "mnp111111111111122222222222222222222333333333333333333333333333xyz ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `HorizontalScrollView` you can just set a property in your `TextView` to make it scroll horizontally

```
android:scrollbars = "horizontal"
```

Then in your java class do this

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```